# coercing to date, "%m/%d/%y" yields wrong year

Tags: r, date, data-conversion

I have used the following code

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

However when I enter `1/4/2016` the output is
`2020-04-01`.

Comment: Necessary reading: `help(strptime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `as.Date(a, "%m/%d/%Y")`, not `as.Date(a, "%m/%d/%y")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

use `%Y`, for 4 digit year.

```
as.Date('1/4/2016', "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Read this  [some examples and learn more here](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

Answer (score 0):

This could be made much more easier by using `mdy` from `lubridate` where it automatically picks up the `%Y` or `%y`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(data$Date)
```